# Sharepoint Client Missing Method

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to connect to my sharepoint site and get a specific list. I found the official docs and tried this:

```cs
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://factionxyz0.sharepoint.com/sites/faktion-devs");
Web web = ctx.Web;
List fileList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestLijst MicrosoftFlow");
CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
ListItemCollection items = fileList.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items);
try
{
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    return req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
}
```

but this just gives me the following error:

> Method not found: 'Void System.Xml.XmlSecureResolver..ctor(System.Xml.XmlResolver, System.Security.PermissionSet)'.

I don't understand why or what is triggering this exception (I'm running this as an Azure Function)

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` package version: `14.0.4762.1000`

Console Output:
[image: Console Output]

Comment: *Which* line causes the exception? Share *full* exception details.

Comment: the line of ctx.ExecuteQuery(); and I have nothing more, the only thing I see popping up in the console: `Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SharePoint Online Tenant, please download and install SharePoint Online CSOM Library here:

[SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

The version should be 16.0.xxxx.xxxx, 14.0.xxxx.xxxx is used in SharePoint 2010.
Once installed the library, you can find the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Client.RunTime.dll in this folder:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI

Here is a sample to use SharePoint Online CSOM inside Azure Function to connection List Item for your reference:

[How To Create Azure Function App To Delete SharePoint Online List Using CSOM](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-azure-function-app-to-delete-sharepoint-online-list-using-csom/)