# SharePoint CSOM ExecuteQuery issue

Tags: asp.net-core, sharepoint-online, .net-framework-version

I am using .Net asp.net core 3.1 web api. One of the action method calls the class library in .Net framework. In class library project, I am using SharePoint CSOM to retrieve the list from SharePoint. When the ExecuteQuery line is executed, below exception is thrown

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Xml.XmlSecureResolver..ctor(System.Xml.XmlResolver, System.Security.PermissionSet)'
```

Class library project works fine when invoked from console application in .net framework. This error pops up, when it is invoked from .net core application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61080289/sharepoint-client-missing-method
You can check this.

Comment: @Aishwarya - I dont want to use the Azure functions. I want to retrieve the data from SharePoint using CSOM dll available for .net framework